# how to repeat local notification if not perform any action in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I am implementing a code for local notifications. My app shows notification and it has two buttons and both buttons have some specific action. Now i want to do when notification will show and user ignore the notification and not click on any button, then it should repeat the notification after one minute. please tell me how to do this.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


class ViewController: UIViewController, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var isGrantedAccess = false
    let time:TimeInterval = 10.0
    var triggered = false

    @IBOutlet weak var checkinDateLbl: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: [.alert,.sound,.badge],
            completionHandler: { (granted,error) in
                self.isGrantedAccess = granted
                if granted{
                    self.setCategories()
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification Access", message: "In order to use this application, turn on notification permissions.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(alertAction)
                    self.present(alert , animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
        })

    }


    @IBAction func saveBtn(_ sender: Any) {

        let checkin = checkinDateLbl.text
        if checkin == "0000-00-00 00:00:00" {
            if isGrantedAccess{
                let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
                content.title = "Attendance Alert"
                content.body = "Please Check In"
                content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
                content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm.category"


                var datee = DateComponents()
                datee.hour = 21
                datee.minute = 50
                let triggerDate = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: datee, repeats: true)
                addNotification(content: content, trigger: triggerDate , indentifier: "Alarm")




            }
        }
    }

    //MARK: - Functions
    func setCategories(){
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snooze", title: "Notify after 30 Minutes", options: [])
        let commentAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "comment", title: "Ignore", options: [])
        let alarmCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alarm.category",actions: [snoozeAction,commentAction],intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([alarmCategory])
    }

    func addNotification(content:UNNotificationContent,trigger:UNNotificationTrigger?, indentifier:String){
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: indentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: {
            (errorObject) in
            if let error = errorObject{
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription) in notification \(indentifier)")
            }
        })

    }

    // MARK: - Delegates
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
    }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let identifier = response.actionIdentifier
        let request = response.notification.request



        if identifier == "snooze"{
            let newContent = request.content.mutableCopy() as! UNMutableNotificationContent
            newContent.title = "Notification"
            newContent.body = "hi"



            let newTrigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: time, repeats: true)
            addNotification(content: newContent, trigger: newTrigger, indentifier: request.identifier)




        }

//        if identifier == "comment"{
//            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
//
//        }

        completionHandler()
    }

}
```

Comment: Perhaps a repeat calendar trigger, and then removing the scheduled notification when the user clicks on a button?

Comment: what's the use case for this?  It seems like something Apple may frown upon, continually showing a notification until user clicks it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no callback to an iOS app when a local notification is actually received in background but not tapped. The only way to achieve this would be to
- Schedule your notification followed by a list of reminder notifications every x mins
- When the user taps your button, remove all the "reminder" notifications

The only problem us that the number of local notifications you can schedule is limited.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications


class ViewController: UIViewController  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        setCategories()

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge]) { granted, error  in

        }

        // 10 seconds from now
        var triggerComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: Date(timeInterval: 10, since: Date()))
        triggerComponents.calendar = Calendar.current


        let content = scheduleAlarm(title: "Alarm", body: "You will be reminded", atDate: triggerComponents)

        // Schedule 10 reminders every 10 seconds
        scheduleReminders(content: content, fromDate: triggerComponents, repeatCount: 10, every: 1, unit: .second)
    }


    func scheduleAlarm(title: String, body: String, atDate dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UNNotificationContent {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = title
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
        content.categoryIdentifier = "alarm.category"

        let calendarTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
        addNotification(content: content, trigger: calendarTrigger , indentifier: "Alarm")

        return content
    }

    /**
     Schedules a serie of reminder notifications from an original notification
     - Parameter content: The content to be scheduled.
     - Parameter fromDate: The date at which was scheduled the original notification
     - Parameter repeatCount: The number of reminders to schedule
     - Parameter every: The interval at which the reminder should be scheduled
     - Parameter unit: The unit of the interval

    */
    func scheduleReminders(content: UNNotificationContent, fromDate dateComponents: DateComponents, repeatCount: Int, every: Int = 1, unit: Calendar.Component = .minute) {

        // schedule the reminders
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        guard let triggerDate = dateComponents.date else { fatalError() }
        for count in 1..<repeatCount {
            // Add the reminder interval and unit to the original notification
            guard let date = calendar.date(byAdding: unit, value: every * count, to: triggerDate)  else { fatalError() }

            let reminderDateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
            let reminderTrigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: reminderDateComponents, repeats: false)
            addNotification(content: content, trigger: reminderTrigger , indentifier: "reminder-\(date.timeIntervalSince1970)")
        }
    }

    /// Removes all pending reminder notifications
    func removeReminderNotifications() {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.getPendingNotificationRequests() { requests in
            // get all pending notifications with identifiers starting with "reminder"
            let reminderIdentifiers = requests.filter({ $0.identifier.starts(with: "reminder")}).map { $0.identifier }
            print("Removing pending reminders: \(reminderIdentifiers)")
            center.removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers: reminderIdentifiers)
        }
    }

    func setCategories() {
        let snoozeAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "snooze", title: "Notify after 30 Minutes", options: [])
        let commentAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "ignore", title: "Ignore", options: [])
        let alarmCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "alarm.category",actions: [snoozeAction,commentAction],intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([alarmCategory])
    }

    func addNotification(content: UNNotificationContent, trigger: UNNotificationTrigger, indentifier: String) {
        print("Scheduling notification at \(trigger)")
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: indentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error \(error.localizedDescription) in notification \(indentifier)")
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getPendingNotificationRequests() { requests in
            print("Pending requests: \(requests.count)")

        }
    }
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        // the user tapped the ignore button, remove all reminders
        if response.actionIdentifier == "ignore" {
            removeReminderNotifications()
        }
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

In fact, there used to be a much easier way using the now deprecated UINotification but I would not recommend using a deprecated framework: https://openradar.appspot.com/26855019